# Installing 10g client next to 11g database on same computer

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-10g, installation, client

I have Oracle 11.2.0.1.0 installed on Windows 7 64 bit

I want to import data from warehouse which has Oracle 10.2.0.4.0 installed.

When I try to import

```
impdp usr/pass@WAREHOUSE TABLES=TABLE DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR NETWORK_LINK=D_W VERSION=10.2
```

It gives :

```
UDI-00018: Data Pump client is incompatible with database version 10.2.0.4.0
```

To overcome version incompatibility, I will install 10g client on my computer.

But I already have 11gr2 database installed, so I wanted to learn about potential problems.

Especially about having two Oracle Homes, tnsnames.ora files, etc..

Thanks.

Comment: Try a filesystem search for impdp.exe.  Do you have more than one?

Comment: I haven't installed 10g client yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could live quiet safety with two ORACLE_HOMEs if you know:

1. %TNS_ADMIN% is your tnsnames.ora / listener.ora / sqlnet.ora directory for both;
2. in your %PATH% you should specify the right order for your preferred oracle bin;
3. there's a Oracle_home_selector installed somehere (I don't remember) in full client install
4. take a look at Windows Registry (something like HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE)
5. pay attention to %NLS_LANG%

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you elaborate it please? Step by step is hihgly appreciated.